# MYSQL Delete Duplicate Records But Keep First Occurrence In Database

Tags: mysql

I have searched for a solution to my question however I cannot find something that exactly matches what I need done.

I have a database with the column `slug` having duplicate entries. I need to delete all duplicates but keep the first occurrence of the row in the database. I cannot just keep the `id` column with the lowest number because they are in different orders in the database for example...

```
id         slug
---------  -----------
4          example-1
3          example-1
2          example-1
1          example-1
5          example-1
```

I would need to keep the slug with the `id` being 5 and delete all other fields with the `slug` being example-1. Is this possible at all?

Comment: How do you identify which one to keep?  Ordering isn't guaranteed until you explicitly `ORDER BY` something.

Comment: Do you want to keep the slug with highest ID? In your example your example the first occurence has ID 4 so it's get kind of confusing what you want.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld no I do not want to keep the one with the highest id which is why I changed my question. I just need the first occurrence of the slug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if there is a syntax to do it in one step.
But for sure, it can be solved in two simple steps.

First select the rows you want to keep into a temporary table.

```
SELECT max(id), slug
FROM your_table
GROUP BY slug
```

Then simply delete all rows which are not in the temp table:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp_table)
```

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific. For some `slug` columns the first occurrence of `id` is not the highest number. I changed my question to reflect that better. But I did not think of using a two step approach. That will probably be the way to go.

Comment: In case you have a condition/rule for indicating which ID you want to keep, my SELECT statement can be adjusted accordingly. I hope the idea of the temp table was useful.

Comment: Yes it was useful. I didn't think of using a two step approach but it worked perfectly for what I needed done. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This should work nicely, but be sure to back up your data just encase.

```
DELETE FROM <table> a INNER JOIN <table> b ON a.slug = b.slug WHERE a.id < b.id;
```